# how to set and consume environment variables in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

so I have a  .env file in my TypeScript-node project. It contains a session variable like this:

```
SESSION_SECRET= EXAMPLEkeyHERE1
 BIRD_STRIPE_KEY= TheseAreNotReAlKeYS
CIRC_STRIPE_KEY= XXXXXX1232abc
```

and Importing using :

`import session = require('express-session'); const { SESSION_SECRET, PORT } = process.env;`

and my app.js looks  like this:

```
if (!SESSION_SECRET) {
logger.error('No client secret. Set SESSION_SECRET environment variable.');
process.exit(1);
}

 /**
 * @description Create Express server.
 */
 const app = express();

if (IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
   /**
    * @description Error Handler. Provides full stack - remove for production
    */
 app.use(errorHandler());
 }

 /**
  * @description Express configuration
  */
  app.set('port', PORT || 3000);
  app.use(
   cors(),
   compression(),
   express.json(),
   session({
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
})
);

/**
 * @description Express routers
 */
const routers = {
     api: express.Router(),
     provider: express.Router()
 };

 routers.api.use([routers.provider]);
 routers.provider.use('/provider', [routes.Bird, routes.Circ, routes.Lime, routes.Spin, routes.Tier]);

/**
 * @description These line will add /api/v{version} route prefix in every api requests.
 */
 app.use(`/api/v${API_CONFIG.versions.v1}`, routers.api);

/**
 * @description These lines are including error404 exported module and it will get called when routes not found.
 */
  app.use([middleware.Error404]);

 /**
 * @var server
 * @description Start Express server.
 */
 app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
     console.log('App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
      console.log('Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
   });
```

when I hit `npm start` I get this error:

```
> @ruler-mobility/ruler@1.0.0 serve /Users/macbook/Desktop/develop/rails-projects/ruler
> node src/app.js

 error: No client secret. Set SESSION_SECRET environment variable. {"service":"user-service"}
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! @ruler-mobility/ruler@1.0.0 serve: `node src/app.js`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

so you can see the error is logged from the first if statement in the code. SESSION_SECRET is a falsy value and hence I'm getting  the error inside the if block

I have tried setting the `SESSION_SECRET` as a string `SESSION_SECRET= "EXAMPLEkeyHERE1"` in my .env file but it made no difference. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

How do I access the variable from the .env file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` to load up env variables:

```js
npm install dotenv -D
```

and then as soon as possible in your script:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

- [Here's the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: how do I use the variable?

Comment: `process.env.VARNAME`

Comment: The real answer is to follow the setup above and then access the environment variables as shown in @aviya 's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me if your problem is reading a configuration file or accessing environment variables.

In order to access environment variables, you just have to use `process.env.VARNAME`. This supposes that the environment variable is properly set, e.g.

```
> SESSION_SECRET="EXAMPLEkeyHERE1" node src/app.js
```

But if you want to put your configuration in a file, you can either use a `.json` file which you `require` or use a library managing configuration, like [confinode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confinode), which will search, load and parse the file for you.